# Intuition behind the (m,n) theorem

Tags: vectors

I don't know if the name of the theorem is absolutely correct but my book states it as (m,n) theorem. [image]

If $m.OA$ and $n.OB$ are two forces that are acting towards $OA$ and $OB$, and $C$ is a point on $AB$ such that $|AC| : |BC| = n : m$ , then the resultant force of the given forces is $(m+n).OC$.

Proof : Applying the triangle law of vectors for $\triangle OAC$ and $\triangle OBC$ we get $$OA + AC = OC....(1)$$$$OB + BC = OC....(2)$$multiplying (1) with m and (2) with n and adding them we get $$mOA + mAC + nOB + nBC = (m+n)OC$$we know that $|AC| : |BC| = n : m$ therefore, $m|AC| = n|BC|$ but from the picture it's clear that the direction of AC and BC are opposite. So they cancel out giving us,$$mOA + nOB = (m+n)OC$$

I get what the theorem is trying to say. But didn't get intuitive sense why what the theorem says actually works. I would like to have an intuitive explanation (an example might be helpful) about this theorem.

Comment: I think the picture is wrong

Comment: The resultant force should be the diagonal of the parallelogram which has the two forces as its sides, OC is just half of it

Comment: well, that is the parallelogram law of forces. But here the discussion is not about that theorem. I have also given the way to prove this theorem, you can test it using this very picture.

Comment: The period in notations like $m.OA$ might be intended to mean to multiply the scalar $m$ and the vector $\vec{OA}$.  If so, that would account for the apparent error pointed out by @LucioTanzini.

Comment: yes, those are intended to be vectors. But if the claim here is wrong then so must be it's proof. But I am not getting where the mistake is. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Sami Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theorem which you are referring to seems to be the [Angle Bisector Theorem](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/AngleBisectorTheorem.shtml).

In the case of forces it doesn't apply since for parallelogram addition rule the resultant vector force passes throught the middle point between A and B.
[image]

Comment: I am a bit confused here...but the theorem has been proved in the textbook using vectors, and I find no fault there. If it doesn't apply for forces(vectors) then there must be some mistake in the proof. I have posted the proof. Can you please point out the mistake?

Comment: I have a doubt about the part if $|AC| : |BC| = n : m$. Like you stated the resultant of two vectors would pass through the midpoint of the diagonal of the parallelogram, So $|AC| : |BC|$ will always be equal to 1 right? So the starting claim that is made to prove this is wrong itself. Isn't it?